# Excel Userform to get outlook display name and email from alias

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a userform with 3 textboxes and 1 button. I want to put an outlook alias into textbox1 (txtPID) and return the display type and email in boxes 2 & 3 (txtName & txtEmail)

this appears to connect to outlook and pull information but it's not searching the alias given in textbox 1

```
Load UsrFrmNewRep

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olGAL As Outlook.AddressList
Dim olMember As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim olAliasName As String
Dim exchuser As Outlook.ExchangeUser


Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olGAL = olNS.AddressLists("Global Address List")

olAliasName = UsrFrmNewRep.txtPID.Value
Set olMember = olGAL.AddressEntries(olAliasName)
Set exchuser = olMember.GetExchangeUser

If Not exchuser Is Nothing Then

UsrFrmNewRep.txtName.Value = exchuser.DisplayType
UsrFrmNewRep.txtEmail.Value = exchuser.PrimarySmtpAddress

End If

End Sub
```

i'm sure i'm not referencing something correctly i'm just not sure what.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `olGAL.AddressEntries(olAliasName)`, use `olNS.CreateRecipient(olAliasName)` / `Recipient.Resolve` / `set olMember = Recipient.AddressEntry`

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, took a bit of trial and error but this worked exactly as I wanted it to.